# AcrGIS Javascript adding graphic on graphicLayer

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a multiple featureLayers and one graphicLayer for adding graphics. However I cannot add a graphic to this layer. Can someone help with what I'm doing wrong?

```
       featureLayer.on("click", function (evt) {
        attrs = evt.graphic.attributes;
        if(clickmode == 1)
        {
           var highlightSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0]));
           var location = new Point(evt.mapPoint.x, evt.mapPoint.y, evt.spatialReference);


           graphicLayer.add(new Graphic(location, highlightSymbol));
        }
      }
```

Comment: Is it throwing any error? better to create a running sample jsfiddle... *Note- verify all the parameters and their value which you are passing to "graphicLayer.add"...

Comment: What is evt.spatialReference? Maybe your map sparitalReference is in meters units and mapPoint in degrees(or vice versa). Check if any graphics added near 0,0 coordinate(west of Africa)